What is this meanign of 匂って?

それからぐっと体寄せた。活発で熱量の多いみのりの体から体温が匂ってくるようだ

The character is training with his crush. He gets close to her and comments this.
how is 匂ってused here? he's talking about her body temp, why is 匂って used?

By "training", do you mean physical exercise? And is みのり her name?

Perhaps this 体温が匂う refers to thermal radiation. Note that verb 匂う, besides smell-related meanings, has meaning "to glow; to be bright​" (in Japanese Wiktionary: 「色づく。かがやく。照り映える。」).

This is scientifically inaccurate but perfectly valid as a novel. The author made it clear that it's a figurative expression by using ようだ. The sentence means "as if I could smell her temperature".
